# How to check whether a Azure blob container can be accessed from iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to check whether I can successfully access an Azure Container of blobs in iOS Swift.  So, I use `AZSCloudBlobContainer.exists(completionHandler: (Error?, Bool) -> Void)` function to make a service call to check whether the container exist.  However, it always tell me the container does not exist, even though I can list/add/delete blobs in that container.  Did I misunderstand the function? and what is the proper way to check the access.  Thanks

```
import AZSClient

let containerURL = "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?st=2019-08-07T18%3A50%3A07Z&se=2019-08-09T18%3A50%3A00Z&sp=racwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=<signature>"
var error: NSError?
var container = AZSCloudBlobContainer(url: URL(string: containerURL)!, error: &error)
container.exists(completionHandler: {(error:Error?, exist:Bool)->Void in
                print("does the contaienr exist? \(exist)")
            })
```

Comment: Do you have a SAS URL for the container?

Comment: yes I do have a SAS URL for the container

Comment: Can you share the SAS token?

Comment: let containerURL = "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?st=2019-08-07T18%3A50%3A07Z&se=2019-08-09T18%3A50%3A00Z&sp=racwl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=<signature>"